# How to test React components inside react-responsive tags

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, media-queries, enzyme, chai-enzyme

Inside a `<MyComponent>` component I am using [`react-responsive`](https://github.com/contra/react-responsive) `<MediaQuery>` components to distinguish between rendering mobile and desktop content.

```
export class MyComponent extends React.Component {

  //...

    render() {
      <MediaQuery query="(max-width: 600)">
        <div className="inside-mobile">mobile view</div>
      </MediaQuery>
    }
}
```

I want to test the HTML inside `<MyComponent>`'s `render()` using `enzyme`, but can't seem to dive into the child elements of `<MediaQuery>`:

```
it('should dive into <MediaQuery>', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(<Provider store={mockedStore}><MyComponent/></Provider>)
    const actual = wrapper.getDOMNode().querySelectorAll(".inside-mobile")       
    expect(actual).to.have.length(1)
}
```

A `console.log(wrapper.debug())`shows that nothing inside `<MediaQuery>` is being rendered, though.
I'm guessing in a test (with no actual browser) `window.width` is not set which leads to the `<MediaQuery>` component not rendering anything.

**What I want to do:**

I want to be able to test `<MyComponent>`'s content using `enzyme` with `react-responsive` (or something similar such as `react-media`) to deal with mobile vs desktop viewports.

**Things I've tried:**

- circumventing this by using `enzyme`'s `shallow` with `dive()` instead of `mount`, to no avail.
- using [`react-media`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-media%20react-media)'s `<Media>` instead of `react-responsive`'s `<MediaQuery>`, which seems to set [`window.matchMedia()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia) to true by default. However, that's not working either.

`console.log(wrapper.debug())` shows:

```
<MyComponent content={{...}}>
    <Media query="(min-width: 600px)" defaultMatches={true} />
</MyComponent>
```

Answer (score 2):

I found a working solution, using [react-media](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-media) instead of [react-responsive](https://github.com/contra/react-responsive), by mocking `window.matchMedia` so that `matches` is set to `true` during the test:

**Create specific media components for different viewports:**

```
const Mobile = ({ children, content }) => <Media query="(max-width: 600px)" children={children}>{matches => matches ? content : "" }</Media>;
const Desktop = ...
```

**Use specific media component:**

```
<MyComponent>
    <Mobile content={
        <div className="mobile">I'm mobile</div>
    }/>
    <Desktop content={...}/>
</MyComponent>
```

**Test content per viewport:**

```
const createMockMediaMatcher = matches => () => ({
    matches,
    addListener: () => {},
    removeListener: () => {}
});

describe('MyComponent', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        window.matchMedia = createMockMediaMatcher(true);
    });

    it('should display the correct text on mobile', () => {

        const wrapper = shallow(<MyComponent/>);
        const mobileView = wrapper.find(Mobile).shallow().dive();
        const actual = mobileView.find(".mobile").text();

        expect(actual).to.equal("I'm mobile");
    });
});
```